# Load different config file in unit test with ConfigFactory

Tags: scala, unit-testing

I have different configuration files in the main application:

- applicaton.conf
- integration.conf
- staging.conf
- production.conf

In the main app, I can load different configurations with the following, where `"integration.conf"` is defined as an environment variable:

```
ConfigFactory.load("integration.conf")
```

However, the same function doesn't seem to work in unit test. Nothing is loaded with the above code. I tried the following, with no parameter, then it loads the default `applicaton.conf` with no problem:

```
ConfigFactory.load()
```

**How do we load a specific config file in the unit test?**

---

I've also tried using a relative path:

```
ConfigFactory.load("../main/resources/integration.conf")
```

and even absolute path:

```
ConfigFactory.load("/Users/.../src/main/resources/integration.conf")
```

But neither of them work.

---

Edit:

I realize that `staging.conf` and `production.conf` are loaded properly after @pedromss's comment. And the only problematic one is `integration.conf`. It is probably because `integration.conf` only has one line:

**integration.conf**:

```
include file("application.conf")
```

It seems that the issue is that `include file("application.conf")` doesn't work? My other configurations for staging and production actually override the default values in `application.conf`:

**staging.conf**:

```
include file("application.conf")
foo {
    bucket="bucket-staging"
}
```

---

It looks like the issue is [`include file("xxx")`](https://github.com/typesafehub/config/issues/146) should be `include "xxx"`. Surprised that only the later works in Unit tests.

Comment: `ConfigFactory.load("<your-specific-filename-here>.conf")` - I tried this with an `integration.conf` in the `src/main/resources` directory and all worked out from my unit tests in `test/scala/MySpec1`

Comment: Hey, @pedromss, thanks for the comments. I realized what was missing after trying `staging.conf` and `production.conf` myself and realized that they work fine. The only configuration file that doesn't work for me is `integration.conf` only contains one line: `include file("application.conf")`. And it seems that the problem is because it is not able to load whatever is specified in the `include`. Do you have any idea? I will put an example of the config file in the question soon.

Comment: `include "application"` in your `integration.conf` file

Comment: That's works!! Thanks a lot! Any insight about why `include file("application.conf")` won't work in this case? If you can write it as an answer, I'll happily mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/typesafehub/config#standard-behavior):

`include "application.conf"` - Then you may override configurations.

`include file("application.conf")` doesn't work and I don't see it in the documentation.